# Inner workings of WCF web.config file

Tags: .net, wcf

Looking for a explanation of the inner workings of WCF web.config file. Specifically these sections.
I have an idea of what they mean but what I'm really looking for is an explanation of the inner workings. For example on

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" />
</protocolMapping>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="DevelopmentBehavior" name="MyCo.Administration.AdminSvcs.AdministrationSvc">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyCo.Administration.AdminSvcs.IAdministrationSvc" bindingConfiguration="DevelopmentBinding" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ProductionBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="DevelopmentBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="DevelopmentBinding">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security> 
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the official documentation? It's at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932.aspx

Because this question isn't very specific, pointing you toward the general, official documentation is about the best I can do, unless you have more questions about it?

Comment: that helps. I'm looking for something more descriptive but that works for now.